# catkin_package INCLUDE_DIR set CFlags to <package>.pc under devel/ but not set CFlags to installspace

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a package with

```
catkin_project(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include1 include2
)
```

and this generate .pc under devel (./devel/lib/pkgconfig/.pc) that contians

```
Cflags: -I.../include1 -I../include2
```

but .pc under build/..../catkin_generated/installspace/.pc becomes

```
Cflags: -I/tmp/catkin_ws/install/include
```

It this expected behavior? Why it is not

`Cflags -I/tmp/catkin_ws/install/include/<package>/include1 -I/tmp/catkin_ws/install/include/<package>/include2`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73297/catkin_package-include_dir-set-cflags-to-%3Cpackage%3E.pc-under-devel/-but-not-set-cflags-to-installspace/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is expected behavior. In install space you should have installed all header (from potentially various locations in source) into a single include folder (following FHS).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-16**:
With catkin, you need to explicitly install any headers you export. See: http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/building_libraries.html#installing

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2013-08-16**:
Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to release 3rd-parity library that does not follows FHS standard, using catkin/bloom. Is there any good examples for this?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-16**:
The link above is the recommended solution.